# Laravel ->put() issue - Mixed content (JSON vs. not JSON)

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm having an issue with using Laravels put() function, as I want put JSON content in this one single scenario.

```php
$datatable->GroupsCollection = $datatable->GroupsCollection->put($job, '{"grade":'.$grade.'}' );
```

But when trying to create 'fake' JSON, the inserted value will be:
`{\"grade\":'VALUE_OF_$GRADE'}`
I've tried using `str_replace()` and `stripslashes()` to cut out the backwardslashes, but no bueno.

I've Googled around, and reading something about a cast was needed in the Model.
So I put in this:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'dvalue' => 'array',
];
```

This result in breaking existing functionality of the code.

```php
public function getGroupsCollectionAttribute()
{
    return collect($this->dvalue ? $this->dvalue['groups'] : null);
}


public function setGroupsCollectionAttribute($value)
{
    $currentValue = $this->dvalue ?? new Collection();
    $this->dvalue['groups'] = $currentValue->$value;
}
```

I 'fixed' the get, but I'm not sure how I should format the 'set' function with this new cast and setting it to an array.

Worth to notice is that we have mixed content in the DB-rows, so it's not always JSON.
Any easier way to go around this?

Comment: Laravel does **not** have a `put()` function. Do you mean [the method of Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-put)?

Comment: Possibly, look at the first code-block. I'm new to Laravel, trying to fixing an existing project.

Comment: Why exactly are you pushing a raw json string into a collection? In some cases it seems desirable, but in most not.

Comment: @Techno Can't tell as I'm only trying to fix an existing project for this one single purpose, without having to doing a hell a lot of refactoring.

Can't I tell Laravel to not make these backward slashes somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ending up fixing it by simply creating an array like this:

```
$grade_json = array("grade" => $grade);
$datatable->GroupsCollection = $datatable->GroupsCollection->put($job, $grade_json);
```